# How verify the report in PDF format

Tags: pdf, automation, ui-automation, browser-automation

[image]

I want to know that how to verify the report. Report is in PDF format and has table or images etc. Image is attached here for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium won't give you direct access to the contents of a PDF file.

Have you looked at [JPDFUnit](http://jpdfunit.sourceforge.net/) (a wrapper around PDFBox)?

I personally would separate the verification of PDF contents from the functional tests based on browser interactions.